# limit superior and limit inferior proof

Tags: calculus, proof-writing, limsup-and-liminf

$$\limsup \left(\frac 1{a_n} \right)=\frac 1{\liminf(a_n )} $$

I know this is true base on the definition of $\limsup$ and $\liminf$, but I don't know how to prove it formally.

Comment: Is it really true? Note that $1/x$ is not a decreasing function. P.S. I am not hinting that its false, I'm just asking: is it true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that a subsequence $a_{n_k} \to a$. Of course we need some assumptions, and I'll assume that $a_n>0$ for any $n$. The $$\frac{1}{a_{n_k}}\to \frac{1}{a},$$ and since $a=\liminf_{n \to +\infty} a_n$ is the smallest possible choice, we deduce at once that the largest possible limit point of $1/a_n$ is $1/a$. Hence $$\frac{1}{a} = \limsup_{n \to +\infty} \frac{1}{a_n}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim \sup \left(\frac {1}{a_n}\right) = \inf_{k=1}^{\infty}\sup_{n=k}^{\infty}\left(\frac {1}{a_n}\right) = \left(\frac {1}{\sup_{k=1}^{\infty}\inf_{n=k}^{\infty} a_n}\right)\dots$$

Comment: You want $\inf,\sup$, not $\min,\max$. I don't see how this is a proof, though.

Comment: If you put $a_n=n/(n-1)$, say, then your max is not defined.

Comment: Still waiting for a real proof.